# Multiple bundle ids for one firebase analytics project

Tags: ios, firebase-analytics

I have an app in the app store where I have a bundle id per territory. I need to have data for all territories in one Firebase Analytics project. This works well in both Flurry and Google Analytics. I am having troubles with Firebase though.

I am currently testing it out in debug mode and events only come in for the bundle id i specified in the plist file. I get an error in the log too:

> "The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in
>   'GoogleService-Info.plist', or the Bundle ID in the options if you are
>   using a customized options. To ensure that everything can be
>   configured correctly, you may need to make the Bundle IDs consistent.
>   To continue with this plist file, you may change your app's bundle
>   identifier to 'com.my.bundleid'. Or you can download a new
>   configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from
>   https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one."

Does anyone know if it can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out it's pretty simple.

For the given project I could just add another app of the same type. This means I can add an app per target and handle the plist files using target membership. This is giving me all the bundle id's in one project.

Unfortunately there is no way to merge the data from the two app's into one report, but that will have to do.